# How can I dump the fscrypt per-file nonce by getfattr command?

Tags: file-system, encryption

According to document of kernel about fscrypt: [Filesystem-level encryption (fscrypt)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fscrypt.html#per-file-encryption-keys):

> Per-file encryption keys
>
> Since each master key can protect many files, it is necessary to “tweak” the encryption of each file so that the same plaintext in two files doesn’t map to the same ciphertext, or vice versa. In most cases, fscrypt does this by deriving per-file keys. When a new encrypted inode (regular file, directory, or symlink) is created, fscrypt randomly generates a 16-byte nonce and stores it in the inode’s encryption xattr. Then, it uses a KDF (as described in Key derivation function) to derive the file’s key from the master key and nonce.

It says that the nonce is stored in xattr. But I can not dump them by getfattr command with dump parameter.

How can I get the nonces?

Comment: tar --xattrs the file and check with hex editor

Comment: thanks @alecxs , There is no tar and other utilities can be used on my device. I have to build a special executable for it. Is there any other more direct way?

Comment: gnu tar binary you can find prebuilt in open gapps. there is easier way but requires lsattr (maybe as busybox applet)